# How to embed local video in a wordpress post

Tags: videos, embed

How can I embed videos (wmv, mp4, mpg, flv) to my post from the local server. I am using WordPress 3.1.1 version. I have searched for wordpress plugins which supports this kind of feature but couldn't find any good plugins. Is there any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You need a media player.  WordPress (and more importantly your server) doesn't know how to play media unless you've got it in via HTML5.  You can use plugins like Viper's Video Quicktags which can parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually entering the HTML code for the `<embed>` in the HTML part of TinyMCE?

Comment: Yes. I have used <embed SRC='sample.mpg' WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=300 AUTOPLAY=false CONTROLLER=true LOOP=false ></embed>. But its asking to install a plugin. I cannot install that plugin.

Comment: I think its an issue with the video format. I could see that the name of the plugin changed when I change the format of video. I have tried wmv and mp4 video, both requires a plugin to work.